# Why is my attempt at night vision goggles not working?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

This is my first attempt at using scoreboards for accomplishing tasks so I'm still learning. I'm trying to make a golden helmet behave as night vision goggles by giving the player the night vision effect.

Here's what I've done so far:

1. Create a dummy objective named "nightVision".
2. Place this command in a clock:

   `scoreboard players set @a nightVision 0`
3. Then this command:

   `scoreboard players set @a nightVision 1 {Inventory:[{Slot:103b,tag:{display:{Name:"Nightvision Goggles",Lore:[Equip to see in the dark!]}}}]}`
4. And finally this command:

   `effect @a[score_nightVision_min:1] 16 30 0 true`

I've tested it by wearing the helmet mentioned above on my head and doing a scoreboard test command. It works if I combine steps 3 and 4 into one testfor command and run a comparator out of it:

```
testfor [player] {Inventory:[{Slot:103b,tag:{display:{Name:"Nightvision Goggles",Lore:[Equip to see in the dark!]}}}]}
```

But that seems like the very thing scoreboards could be used to avoid.

I've tried taking out the first command because I thought maybe the scores were being reset too fast but it still doesn't work. I've come to the conclusion that my error is either in step 3 or step 4 but I'm not seeing it.

Comment: You say you have a clock running, are you certain it's running?

Comment: Yes. I can run "scoreboard players test" on myself and see that the score for nightVision is 1 when I'm wearing the helmet and 0 when I'm not. The only place those are changed are on that clock.

Comment: Are you sure that the order the commands are running in is correct? Because the reset command has to be after the others

Comment: There is an error in step 4, where you use a colon in the target selector instead of an equals sign. Is that just a typo? If not, change it to `score_nightVision_min=1`

Comment: I got it working. I believe it was a combination of what PangeaCake suggested as well as the error in syntax that MrLemon pointed out. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As MrLemon has pointed out in the comments, there is an error in your fourth step, where the command is:

`effect @a[score_nightVision_min:1] 16 30 0 true`

You have to replace the colon ( **:** ) with an equals sign ( **=** ) for that part to work.

Comment: Additionally I also had the commands executing in the wrong order. Silly me.